# python IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable in jupyter

Tags: python

I am trying to make a go through the image files in python.
I keep getting the indexError in eachPix[:3] in function threshold.

The code is about loading png data and loading the image data.

```
#folerLoader is a function returning list of files and target. 
pathlist is a list of paths of pictures

dfin = loadImageData(pathlist,target)

#loads image data
def loadImageData(pathList, target):
    finalList = []
    for path in pathList:
        im = Image.open(path, 'r')
        resizedIm = im.resize([28,28])
        image = np.asarray(resizedIm)
        imageThreshold = threshold(image)
        imageRow = imageThreshold.flatten()
        finalList.append(imageRow)
    df = pd.DataFrame(finalList)
    df['class'] = target
    return df

def threshold(imageArray):
    balanceAr = []
    for eachRow in imageArray:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum = mean(eachPix[:3]) # where I get error
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)
    balance = mean(balanceAr)

    newMat = []
    for eachRow in imageArray:
        newRow = []
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            if mean(eachPix[:1]) > balance:
                newRow.append(255)

            else:
                newRow.append(0)
        newMat.append(newRow)

    return np.array(newMat)
```

please help me how to solve the problem.

Error came out like below

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-c6a21e1399e7> in <module>
----> 1 dfin = loadImageData(pathlist,target)

<ipython-input-76-8dd1c50d3083> in loadImageData(pathList, target)
      5         resizedIm = im.resize([28,28])
      6         image = np.asarray(resizedIm)
----> 7         imageThreshold = threshold(image)
      8         imageRow = imageThreshold.flatten()
      9         finalList.append(imageRow)

<ipython-input-90-876634931686> in threshold(imageArray)
      4         for eachPix in eachRow:
      5             x=3
----> 6             avgNum = mean(eachPix[:x])
      7             balanceAr.append(avgNum)
      8     balance = mean(balanceAr)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the full error output?

Comment: I have edited with the error message

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, complete, verifiable example]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.   Your posted code fails to run and is far from minimal.

Comment: The error is straightforward: `eachPix` is a scalar value; you tried to take a slice of it.  This is illegal.  Since you neglected to trace the offending values, there's not much we can do for you.